# Snowflake - Query Last 12 Months of Data

Tags: sql, date, where-clause, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

How would I pull the last twelve months of records without using Between? I've attempted variations of the following in my where clause :

```
DATEADD(YEAR,-12,O.CREATEDATE)
```

&

```
TO_DATE(O.CREATEDATE)>=DATEADD(YEAR,-12,O.CREATEDATE)
```

The ***Snowflake*** documentation on this SQL function appears to explain how the datadd simply changes the date. Is there a ***snowflake sql*** function that will execute this type of request?

Thank you kindly

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would use:

```
where o.createdate >= dateadd(year, -1, current_date)
```

Comment: Ah, "current_date" is the trick...sorry about the "12" there in the code part.